# Creating a view inside of SegmentedPickerStyle Picker in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to put a view inside of SegmentedPickerStyle `Picker`.
The view I'm trying to put is just simple like this:

```
VStack{
Text("text1")
Text("text1")
}
```

And below are what I have tried to achieve this

try1

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    let options = ["AAA", "BBB"]
    var body: some View {
       Picker(selection: self.$selected, label: Text("")) {
        
        ForEach(0..<self.options.count) {number in
            VStack{
                Text("\(self.options[number])")
                Text("some text")
            }
      }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

try2

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selected = 0
    let options = ["AAA", "BBB"]
    var body: some View {
       Picker(selection: self.$selected, label: Text("")) {
        
        ForEach(0..<self.options.count) {number in
            
                Text("""
                    \(self.options[number])
                    some text
                    """)
      }
        }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
    }
}
```

But above both ways don't produce the result I want, Would be there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not supported for now. Here is what Apple says (pay attention on *Note*):

```
/// A picker style that presents the options in a segmented control.
///
/// To apply this style to a picker, or to a view that contains pickers, use the
/// ``View/pickerStyle(_:)`` modifier.
///
/// > Note: The segmented picker style supports ``Text`` and ``Image`` segments only.
/// Any other view results in a visible, but empty, segment.
@available(iOS 13.0, OSX 10.15, tvOS 13.0, *)
@available(watchOS, unavailable)
public struct SegmentedPickerStyle : PickerStyle {
```